# Autocomplete for AngularJS not working in PhpStorm / WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm, webstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I'm trying to solve the following problem in my PhpStorm 2017.1:

In templates autocompletion for `ng-*` is not working and the IDE is highlighting `ng-`Attributes as not allowed:

[image: Attribute ng-if is not allowed here]

In directives and services it does not recognize `angular.module()`:

[image: Unresolved function or method module()]

(it seems to know "factory" though)

I already installed the AngularJS and Angular Templates plugin...

[image]

... as well as downloaded the angular library:

[image]

What else could I try to solve this?

Edit: To follow up on lena's answer: I included AngularJS via bower. But the bower settings show no bower dependencies, although there are many in the bower.json:

[image]

Also when clicking on the plus button to install new packages I get this error:

[image]

So maybe that's the root of the problem? In the command line bower is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From screenshots it seems that AngularJS support is not enabled - built-in directives not recognized, all methods shown as plain text.
Do you have `angular.js` file (debug version, not minified/scrambled) in your project (either in your project directory or configured as JavaScript library)? Normally it's enough to get Angular directives/methods recognized. Note that Typescript stubs ('definitely typed') won't work here, it should be a js library. See http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/, 'Include angular.js in Your Project' section.

Comment: I installed AngularJS via bower. According to the link you provided that is supposed to work out of the box. I edited my question, maybe you could have another look?

Comment: problem listing dependencies unlikely has a relation to the issue. Do you have your dependencies installed locally? Is bower_components folder included in project (not marked as excluded)?

Comment: bower_components folder was indeed marked as excluded. Cancelling the exclusion solved the problem. Thanks for the hint. However now the IDE is indexing and searching over that folder, which I prevented by excluding it. I guess I have to live with one problem or the other...

Answer (score 1):

I had my `node_modules` directory flagged as "Excluded". Changing it to "Library root" and installing "angular": "^1.8.2" worked well for telling IntelliJ to recognize that this is an Angular project.